# Removing redundant lines of code which differ by only one list index value

Tags: python

I have a number of lines of code which are quite repetitve, only differing by one integer.

```
def my_function(row):    
    ozone = row[1].text.replace('\xa0', ' ').split(' ')[0]
    no2 = row[2].text.replace('\xa0', ' ').split(' ')[0]
    so2 = row[3].text.replace('\xa0', ' ').split(' ')[0]
    pm10 = row[4].text.replace('\xa0', ' ').split(' ')[0]
    return {'ozone': ozone, 'no2': no2, 'so2': so2, 'pm10': pm10}
```

I would like to clean up this code, if possible, by doing something like the following:

```
def my_function(row):    
    foo = row[{}].text.replace('\xa0', ' ').split(' ')[0]
    return {'ozone': foo.format(1), 'no2': foo.format(2), 'so2': foo.format(3), 'pm10': foo.format(4)}
```

Obviously the str format method won't work, but hopefully you can see what I aim to do. How can I do this in a pythonic way?

Comment: When you use the same piece of code a lot, you put it in a function. That's what they're for.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through a slice of `row`, process each item and zip the results with the dictionary keys:

```
def my_function(row):
    keys = ('ozone', 'no2', 'so2', 'pm10')
    values = [x.text.replace('\xa0', ' ').split(' ')[0] for x in row[1:5]]   
    return dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the duplication of the replacing but I'd still keep the same number of rows for readability..

```
values = []
for i in range(1,5):
    values.append(row[i].text.replace('\xa0', ' ').split(' ')[0])

ozone, no2, so2, pm10 = values
return {'ozone': ozone, 'no2': no2, 'so2': so2, 'pm10': pm10}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split in two functions, one doing the replacing, splitting and returning. And the other one which you initially had. The second one contains groups, where each entry in the group contains the row index and the key that it maps to.

```
def replace_split_and_return_first(text):
    return text.replace('\xa0', ' ').split(' ')[0]

def my_function(row):
    groups = [(1, 'ozone'), (2, 'no2'), (3, 'so2'), (4, 'pm10')]
    return {key: replace_split_and_return_first(row[idx].text) for (idx, key) in groups}
```